# Creating a text file with no newline at the end of it

Tags: text

I am using `ldapsearch` with its `-y` option where the password for the ldap server is read in from a file in order to ensure that the password is not left in the command history.

`ldapsearch` requires that the password be in a file with no newlines. The only way I am aware of for doing this is:

```
echo -n "myreallysecretpassword" > /path/to/password.txt
```

but obviously that puts the password in the command history, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I assume there's a better way, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're using `bash`, check your `HISTCONTROL`.  Typically, if you prefix your command with a space, it will not be stored in your history.

Comment: Sadly our machines don't have HISTCONTROL set, and I can't really change those settings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the file however you want and just printf it without newline.

```
cat pw.txt | awk '{printf $1 }'
```

or

```
printf `cat pw.txt`
```

Comment: That works great, but it still means that the password appears in the process list if someone manages to view it at just the right time. In the end I have combined your answer with @Eduardo's: cat password.txt | awk '{printf $1}' > new_password.txt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use read to input an intermediate variable semi-securely:

```
read -s tempvar # enter your password and press enter - it will not echo back
echo -n $tempvar > pw.txt
unset tempvar
```

Of course if you're worried mostly about the command history you can disable it in bash like this:

```
export HISTFILE=
```